# How can I do to finish a program with a read of a String?

Tags: c, string

I need read a string and finish it. For example:

**INPUT**

```
fxy yxf
abc bac
weq qew
abg bga
acd adc
abt bta
poeq eopq
qwte wtqe
```

I want to finish the program after the word "wtqe".

**Here is my code:**

```
int main(){

   do {

       scanf("%s %s", &str1, &str2);

   }while(scanf("%c") != EOF);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem with your program? Do you get build errors? Crashes? Unexpected results? Please create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: The problem is that after DO-WHILE has a "return 0;" in main. But it does not end because it loops and does not end the loop.

Comment: Why don't you just test `str2` if its value is `"wtqe"`?

Comment: Because it can be any word, not necessarily "wtqe".

Comment: Do you mean that if there was more data after `wtqe`, you'd still want to stop on reading it, or that you want to stop when you reach the end of file? There are different sets of problems to deal with. With input, though, `do { … } while (…);` loops are often not as sensible as `while (scanf("%s%s", str1, str2) == 2) { … }` which checks the condition directly at the top of the loop. Your `scanf("%c")` is missing an argument; it also reads a character.  Fortunately for you, it'd probably be a newline, but be cautious.  (The `%s` string skips newlines and other white space automatically anyway.)

Answer (score 3):

The end of the loop is `while(scanf("%c") != EOF)`

This means that the loop quits when you reach end-of-file.

If you put all of those in a text file, and ran your program with that file as standard input (`./prog < file`), then it will quit after it finishes reading the file.

If you want to type all of those in, you need to indicate end-of-file to the terminal. On Linux, Mac, and similar systems, you do this with ctrl+d; on Windows I think it's ctrl-z.

---

Edit to add: This will give strange results if the very start of the input doesn't match. A better option might be

```
while (scanf("%s %s", &str1, &str2) == 2) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

As shown by [user3121023's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46267603/27302), this can also cause buffer overflow issues, and you should give an explicit size to `%s`.

Comment: @DavidBowling Good point; I'm more used to C++ and get the details of I/O wrong in pretty much every language. I've updated my answer, but there are still better options if you want to distinguish between a single string and no strings.

Comment: @user3121023 Oh, I thought it consumed *trailing* whitespace, not *leading* whitespace. I'll edit again. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use fgets to read a line and sscanf to parse the two strings. If a blank line is entered or a line with only one string, the while loop will exit.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    char line[999] = "";
    char str1[100] = "";
    char str2[100] = "";
    int result = 0;

    do {
        if ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
            result = sscanf  ( line, "%99s%99s", str1, str2);
        }
        else {//fgets failed
            break;
        }
    } while ( line[0] != '\n' && result == 2);

    return 0;
}
```